# How to use transactions in php to execute multiple queries but preventing SQL INJECTIONS

Tags: php, transactions

I am trying to execute two sql queries in the same time with mysqli:: multi_query and it works. Using this method I am not preventing SQL Injections. Multi_query method is not supported for prepared statements so I searched in Internet what to do instead of this. **"TRANSACTIONS"**  was the Solution. I wrote my code like this but it doesn't work. None of these queries is executed. I want them to execute in the same time. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong ?

```
<?php   
 $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'security') 
 mysqli_autocommit($conn, FALSE); 

 $sql = 'update users set name=?,surname=?,nickname=?,rfidcode=? where rfidcode=?';
 $sql2="delete from access_rights where users_rfidcode=?";

 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);    
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssss', $name,$surname,$nickname,$rfid,$rfidcode);

 $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql2);    
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, 's', $rfidcode);

 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
?>
```

Queries are ok because I have tested them and they work fine. Where can the problem be ?

Comment: you don't appear to be [committing](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php) your transaction.

Comment: and why would you want to run all the queries in a single query() call? you've got a transaction going, you don't have to send over all the queries at once. you CAN do individual prepare/bind/execute() calls in sequence, all part of the SAME transaction.

Comment: Thank You  @Orangepill it works now :D

Comment: also you are not starting in an actual transaction. use [mysqli_begin_transaction](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) . Right now it is possible that your two queries can fail independently of one another.